# Optimize Oracle Query - for View

Tags: sql, oracle, join, query-optimization

I have single question, to optimize a View Query using Oracle. Is there anyone able to help me out.

I'm about to select **circuitname** and **oldname** (the old name of **circuitname**) from only one table. But each **circuitname**, possibly has more than 1 sub name (**oldname**, **sub-oldname**, etc), and i want to *join* all of them with this View Query. This query is good, but when I select 1 by 1 **circuitname, oldname, sub-oldname**, etc until 20 **circuitname**, it takes too much time. I want to optimize the query, to perform less time, before the app timeout.
Here's the query

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "IMS"."VW_SI_CASCADE" ("R1", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14", "L15", "L16", "L17", "L18", "L19", "L20", "L21", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20", "M21") AS 
  SELECT
    ROWNUM AS R1,
    V1.OLDNAME AS L1, 
    V1.CIRCUITNAME AS L2, 
    V2.CIRCUITNAME AS L3, 
    V3.CIRCUITNAME AS L4,  
    V4.CIRCUITNAME AS L5,  
    V5.CIRCUITNAME AS L6,  
    V6.CIRCUITNAME AS L7,  
    V7.CIRCUITNAME AS L8, 
    V8.CIRCUITNAME AS L9,  
    V9.CIRCUITNAME AS L10,  
    V10.CIRCUITNAME AS L11, 
    V11.CIRCUITNAME AS L12, 
    V12.CIRCUITNAME AS L13, 
    V13.CIRCUITNAME AS L14, 
    V14.CIRCUITNAME AS L15, 
    V15.CIRCUITNAME AS L16, 
    V16.CIRCUITNAME AS L17, 
    V17.CIRCUITNAME AS L18, 
    V18.CIRCUITNAME AS L19, 
    V19.CIRCUITNAME AS L20, 
    V20.CIRCUITNAME AS L21,
    V1.OLDCIRCUITID AS M1,
    V1.CIRCUITID AS M2, 
    V2.CIRCUITID AS M3, 
    V3.CIRCUITID AS M4,  
    V4.CIRCUITID AS M5,  
    V5.CIRCUITID AS M6,  
    V6.CIRCUITID AS M7,  
    V7.CIRCUITID AS M8, 
    V8.CIRCUITID AS M9,  
    V9.CIRCUITID AS M10,  
    V10.CIRCUITID AS M11, 
    V11.CIRCUITID AS M12, 
    V12.CIRCUITID AS M13, 
    V13.CIRCUITID AS M14, 
    V14.CIRCUITID AS M15, 
    V15.CIRCUITID AS M16, 
    V16.CIRCUITID AS M17, 
    V17.CIRCUITID AS M18, 
    V18.CIRCUITID AS M19, 
    V19.CIRCUITID AS M20, 
    V20.CIRCUITID AS M21
    FROM VW_SI_OLDNAME V1 
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V2 ON V2.OLDNAME = V1.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V3 ON V3.OLDNAME = V2.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V4 ON V4.OLDNAME = V3.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V5 ON V5.OLDNAME = V4.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V6 ON V6.OLDNAME = V5.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V7 ON V7.OLDNAME = V6.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V8 ON V8.OLDNAME = V7.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V9 ON V9.OLDNAME = V8.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V10 ON V10.OLDNAME = V9.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V11 ON V11.OLDNAME = V10.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V12 ON V12.OLDNAME = V11.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V13 ON V13.OLDNAME = V12.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V14 ON V14.OLDNAME = V13.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V15 ON V15.OLDNAME = V14.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V16 ON V16.OLDNAME = V15.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V17 ON V17.OLDNAME = V16.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V18 ON V18.OLDNAME = V17.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V19 ON V19.OLDNAME = V18.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN VW_SI_OLDNAME V20 ON V20.OLDNAME = V19.CIRCUITNAME;
```

Pardon if I have any mistakes, and kindly need your help guys, my fellow heroes!

Comment: How do you use `VW_SI_CASCADE` exactly? Could you provide most often real queries that use it?

Comment: And it would be better to see DDL of `VW_SI_OLDNAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying the view twenty times. That's going to be slow. You could try using subquery factoring, so you query the view **once** and re-use the result set multiple times.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "IMS"."VW_SI_CASCADE" ("R1", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14", "L15", "L16", "L17", "L18", "L19", "L20", "L21", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10", "M11", "M12", "M13", "M14", "M15", "M16", "M17", "M18", "M19", "M20", "M21") AS 
  
  with cte as (
    select * from VW_SI_OLDNAME
  )

  SELECT
    ROWNUM AS R1,
    V1.OLDNAME AS L1, 
    V1.CIRCUITNAME AS L2, 
    V2.CIRCUITNAME AS L3, 
    V3.CIRCUITNAME AS L4,  
    V4.CIRCUITNAME AS L5,  
    V5.CIRCUITNAME AS L6,  
    V6.CIRCUITNAME AS L7,  
    V7.CIRCUITNAME AS L8, 
    V8.CIRCUITNAME AS L9,  
    V9.CIRCUITNAME AS L10,  
    V10.CIRCUITNAME AS L11, 
    V11.CIRCUITNAME AS L12, 
    V12.CIRCUITNAME AS L13, 
    V13.CIRCUITNAME AS L14, 
    V14.CIRCUITNAME AS L15, 
    V15.CIRCUITNAME AS L16, 
    V16.CIRCUITNAME AS L17, 
    V17.CIRCUITNAME AS L18, 
    V18.CIRCUITNAME AS L19, 
    V19.CIRCUITNAME AS L20, 
    V20.CIRCUITNAME AS L21,
    V1.OLDCIRCUITID AS M1,
    V1.CIRCUITID AS M2, 
    V2.CIRCUITID AS M3, 
    V3.CIRCUITID AS M4,  
    V4.CIRCUITID AS M5,  
    V5.CIRCUITID AS M6,  
    V6.CIRCUITID AS M7,  
    V7.CIRCUITID AS M8, 
    V8.CIRCUITID AS M9,  
    V9.CIRCUITID AS M10,  
    V10.CIRCUITID AS M11, 
    V11.CIRCUITID AS M12, 
    V12.CIRCUITID AS M13, 
    V13.CIRCUITID AS M14, 
    V14.CIRCUITID AS M15, 
    V15.CIRCUITID AS M16, 
    V16.CIRCUITID AS M17, 
    V17.CIRCUITID AS M18, 
    V18.CIRCUITID AS M19, 
    V19.CIRCUITID AS M20, 
    V20.CIRCUITID AS M21
    FROM cte V1 
LEFT JOIN cte V2 ON V2.OLDNAME = V1.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V3 ON V3.OLDNAME = V2.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V4 ON V4.OLDNAME = V3.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V5 ON V5.OLDNAME = V4.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V6 ON V6.OLDNAME = V5.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V7 ON V7.OLDNAME = V6.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V8 ON V8.OLDNAME = V7.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V9 ON V9.OLDNAME = V8.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V10 ON V10.OLDNAME = V9.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V11 ON V11.OLDNAME = V10.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V12 ON V12.OLDNAME = V11.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V13 ON V13.OLDNAME = V12.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V14 ON V14.OLDNAME = V13.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V15 ON V15.OLDNAME = V14.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V16 ON V16.OLDNAME = V15.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V17 ON V17.OLDNAME = V16.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V18 ON V18.OLDNAME = V17.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V19 ON V19.OLDNAME = V18.CIRCUITNAME
LEFT JOIN cte V20 ON V20.OLDNAME = V19.CIRCUITNAME;
```

Beyond that you may need to consider the internal logic of the view. There may be a better way to re-construct the chain of names. You also might be exposed to cycles in the re-naming.

Comment: It worked Sir! The query is going to be more efficient, thanks a lot, for your answer and knowledge, Sir :D

Answer (score 0):

For example, your `VW_SI_OLDNAME` contains a data like this:

```
with VW_SI_OLDNAME  as (
  select 
    'name_'||to_char(level-1,'fm0000') OLDNAME 
   ,'name_'||to_char(level  ,'fm0000') CIRCUITNAME
   ,level-1 OLDCIRCUITID
   ,level CIRCUITID
  from dual
  connect by level<=100
)
select * 
from VW_SI_OLDNAME;
```

Example:

```
OLDNAME    CIRCUITNAM OLDCIRCUITID  CIRCUITID
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
name_0000  name_0001             0          1
name_0001  name_0002             1          2
name_0002  name_0003             2          3
name_0003  name_0004             3          4
name_0004  name_0005             4          5
...
name_0028  name_0029            28         29
name_0029  name_0030            29         30
name_0030  name_0031            30         31
...
name_0097  name_0098            97         98
name_0098  name_0099            98         99
name_0099  name_0100            99        100
```

In this case, you can easily create your view using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` that will scan  your `VW_SI_OLDNAME` just once:

```sql
VW_SI_CASCADE as (
  select * 
  from VW_SI_OLDNAME
  match_recognize(
   MEASURES 
            classifier() event
           ,match_number() match
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,1) CIRCUITID_1
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,2) CIRCUITID_2
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,3) CIRCUITID_3
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,4) CIRCUITID_4
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,5) CIRCUITID_5
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,6) CIRCUITID_6
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,7) CIRCUITID_7
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,8) CIRCUITID_8
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,1) CIRCUITNAME_1
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,2) CIRCUITNAME_2
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,3) CIRCUITNAME_3
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,4) CIRCUITNAME_4
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,5) CIRCUITNAME_5
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,6) CIRCUITNAME_6
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,7) CIRCUITNAME_7
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,8) CIRCUITNAME_8
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH 
   PATTERN (p) 
   DEFINE 
    p AS OLDNAME = prev(CIRCUITNAME)
  )
)
```

I've created only 1-8 just to make this example shorter.

Full example with test data:

```sql
with
 VW_SI_OLDNAME  as (
  select 
    'name_'||to_char(level-1,'fm0000') OLDNAME 
   ,'name_'||to_char(level  ,'fm0000') CIRCUITNAME
   ,level-1 OLDCIRCUITID
   ,level CIRCUITID
  from dual
  connect by level<=100
)
,VW_SI_CASCADE as (
  select * 
  from VW_SI_OLDNAME
  match_recognize(
   MEASURES 
            classifier() event
           ,match_number() match
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,1) CIRCUITID_1
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,2) CIRCUITID_2
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,3) CIRCUITID_3
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,4) CIRCUITID_4
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,5) CIRCUITID_5
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,6) CIRCUITID_6
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,7) CIRCUITID_7
           ,prev(CIRCUITID,8) CIRCUITID_8
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,1) CIRCUITNAME_1
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,2) CIRCUITNAME_2
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,3) CIRCUITNAME_3
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,4) CIRCUITNAME_4
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,5) CIRCUITNAME_5
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,6) CIRCUITNAME_6
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,7) CIRCUITNAME_7
           ,prev(CIRCUITNAME,8) CIRCUITNAME_8
   ALL ROWS PER MATCH 
   PATTERN (p) 
   DEFINE 
    p AS OLDNAME = prev(CIRCUITNAME)
  )
)
select *
from VW_SI_CASCADE;
```

Results:

```
EVENT  MATCH CIRCUITID_1 CIRCUITID_2 CIRCUITID_3 CIRCUITID_4 CIRCUITID_5 CIRCUITID_6 CIRCUITID_7 CIRCUITID_8 CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM CIRCUITNAM OLDNAME    CIRCUITNAM OLDCIRCUITID  CIRCUITID
----- ------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ----------
P          1           1                                                                                     name_0001                                                                               name_0001  name_0002             1          2
P          2           2           1                                                                         name_0002  name_0001                                                                    name_0002  name_0003             2          3
P          3           3           2           1                                                             name_0003  name_0002  name_0001                                                         name_0003  name_0004             3          4
P          4           4           3           2           1                                                 name_0004  name_0003  name_0002  name_0001                                              name_0004  name_0005             4          5
P          5           5           4           3           2           1                                     name_0005  name_0004  name_0003  name_0002  name_0001                                   name_0005  name_0006             5          6
P          6           6           5           4           3           2           1                         name_0006  name_0005  name_0004  name_0003  name_0002  name_0001                        name_0006  name_0007             6          7
P          7           7           6           5           4           3           2           1             name_0007  name_0006  name_0005  name_0004  name_0003  name_0002  name_0001             name_0007  name_0008             7          8
P          8           8           7           6           5           4           3           2           1 name_0008  name_0007  name_0006  name_0005  name_0004  name_0003  name_0002  name_0001  name_0008  name_0009             8          9
P          9           9           8           7           6           5           4           3           2 name_0009  name_0008  name_0007  name_0006  name_0005  name_0004  name_0003  name_0002  name_0009  name_0010             9         10
P         10          10           9           8           7           6           5           4           3 name_0010  name_0009  name_0008  name_0007  name_0006  name_0005  name_0004  name_0003  name_0010  name_0011            10         11
P         11          11          10           9           8           7           6           5           4 name_0011  name_0010  name_0009  name_0008  name_0007  name_0006  name_0005  name_0004  name_0011  name_0012            11         12
P         12          12          11          10           9           8           7           6           5 name_0012  name_0011  name_0010  name_0009  name_0008  name_0007  name_0006  name_0005  name_0012  name_0013            12         13
P         13          13          12          11          10           9           8           7           6 name_0013  name_0012  name_0011  name_0010  name_0009  name_0008  name_0007  name_0006  name_0013  name_0014            13         14
P         14          14          13          12          11          10           9           8           7 name_0014  name_0013  name_0012  name_0011  name_0010  name_0009  name_0008  name_0007  name_0014  name_0015            14         15
P         15          15          14          13          12          11          10           9           8 name_0015  name_0014  name_0013  name_0012  name_0011  name_0010  name_0009  name_0008  name_0015  name_0016            15         16
P         16          16          15          14          13          12          11          10           9 name_0016  name_0015  name_0014  name_0013  name_0012  name_0011  name_0010  name_0009  name_0016  name_0017            16         17
P         17          17          16          15          14          13          12          11          10 name_0017  name_0016  name_0015  name_0014  name_0013  name_0012  name_0011  name_0010  name_0017  name_0018            17         18
P         18          18          17          16          15          14          13          12          11 name_0018  name_0017  name_0016  name_0015  name_0014  name_0013  name_0012  name_0011  name_0018  name_0019            18         19
P         19          19          18          17          16          15          14          13          12 name_0019  name_0018  name_0017  name_0016  name_0015  name_0014  name_0013  name_0012  name_0019  name_0020            19         20
P         20          20          19          18          17          16          15          14          13 name_0020  name_0019  name_0018  name_0017  name_0016  name_0015  name_0014  name_0013  name_0020  name_0021            20         21
P         21          21          20          19          18          17          16          15          14 name_0021  name_0020  name_0019  name_0018  name_0017  name_0016  name_0015  name_0014  name_0021  name_0022            21         22
P         22          22          21          20          19          18          17          16          15 name_0022  name_0021  name_0020  name_0019  name_0018  name_0017  name_0016  name_0015  name_0022  name_0023            22         23
P         23          23          22          21          20          19          18          17          16 name_0023  name_0022  name_0021  name_0020  name_0019  name_0018  name_0017  name_0016  name_0023  name_0024            23         24
P         24          24          23          22          21          20          19          18          17 name_0024  name_0023  name_0022  name_0021  name_0020  name_0019  name_0018  name_0017  name_0024  name_0025            24         25
P         25          25          24          23          22          21          20          19          18 name_0025  name_0024  name_0023  name_0022  name_0021  name_0020  name_0019  name_0018  name_0025  name_0026            25         26
P         26          26          25          24          23          22          21          20          19 name_0026  name_0025  name_0024  name_0023  name_0022  name_0021  name_0020  name_0019  name_0026  name_0027            26         27
P         27          27          26          25          24          23          22          21          20 name_0027  name_0026  name_0025  name_0024  name_0023  name_0022  name_0021  name_0020  name_0027  name_0028            27         28
P         28          28          27          26          25          24          23          22          21 name_0028  name_0027  name_0026  name_0025  name_0024  name_0023  name_0022  name_0021  name_0028  name_0029            28         29
P         29          29          28          27          26          25          24          23          22 name_0029  name_0028  name_0027  name_0026  name_0025  name_0024  name_0023  name_0022  name_0029  name_0030            29         30
P         30          30          29          28          27          26          25          24          23 name_0030  name_0029  name_0028  name_0027  name_0026  name_0025  name_0024  name_0023  name_0030  name_0031            30         31
P         31          31          30          29          28          27          26          25          24 name_0031  name_0030  name_0029  name_0028  name_0027  name_0026  name_0025  name_0024  name_0031  name_0032            31         32
P         32          32          31          30          29          28          27          26          25 name_0032  name_0031  name_0030  name_0029  name_0028  name_0027  name_0026  name_0025  name_0032  name_0033            32         33
P         33          33          32          31          30          29          28          27          26 name_0033  name_0032  name_0031  name_0030  name_0029  name_0028  name_0027  name_0026  name_0033  name_0034            33         34
P         34          34          33          32          31          30          29          28          27 name_0034  name_0033  name_0032  name_0031  name_0030  name_0029  name_0028  name_0027  name_0034  name_0035            34         35
P         35          35          34          33          32          31          30          29          28 name_0035  name_0034  name_0033  name_0032  name_0031  name_0030  name_0029  name_0028  name_0035  name_0036            35         36
P         36          36          35          34          33          32          31          30          29 name_0036  name_0035  name_0034  name_0033  name_0032  name_0031  name_0030  name_0029  name_0036  name_0037            36         37
P         37          37          36          35          34          33          32          31          30 name_0037  name_0036  name_0035  name_0034  name_0033  name_0032  name_0031  name_0030  name_0037  name_0038            37         38
P         38          38          37          36          35          34          33          32          31 name_0038  name_0037  name_0036  name_0035  name_0034  name_0033  name_0032  name_0031  name_0038  name_0039            38         39
P         39          39          38          37          36          35          34          33          32 name_0039  name_0038  name_0037  name_0036  name_0035  name_0034  name_0033  name_0032  name_0039  name_0040            39         40
P         40          40          39          38          37          36          35          34          33 name_0040  name_0039  name_0038  name_0037  name_0036  name_0035  name_0034  name_0033  name_0040  name_0041            40         41
P         41          41          40          39          38          37          36          35          34 name_0041  name_0040  name_0039  name_0038  name_0037  name_0036  name_0035  name_0034  name_0041  name_0042            41         42
P         42          42          41          40          39          38          37          36          35 name_0042  name_0041  name_0040  name_0039  name_0038  name_0037  name_0036  name_0035  name_0042  name_0043            42         43
P         43          43          42          41          40          39          38          37          36 name_0043  name_0042  name_0041  name_0040  name_0039  name_0038  name_0037  name_0036  name_0043  name_0044            43         44
P         44          44          43          42          41          40          39          38          37 name_0044  name_0043  name_0042  name_0041  name_0040  name_0039  name_0038  name_0037  name_0044  name_0045            44         45
P         45          45          44          43          42          41          40          39          38 name_0045  name_0044  name_0043  name_0042  name_0041  name_0040  name_0039  name_0038  name_0045  name_0046            45         46
P         46          46          45          44          43          42          41          40          39 name_0046  name_0045  name_0044  name_0043  name_0042  name_0041  name_0040  name_0039  name_0046  name_0047            46         47
P         47          47          46          45          44          43          42          41          40 name_0047  name_0046  name_0045  name_0044  name_0043  name_0042  name_0041  name_0040  name_0047  name_0048            47         48
P         48          48          47          46          45          44          43          42          41 name_0048  name_0047  name_0046  name_0045  name_0044  name_0043  name_0042  name_0041  name_0048  name_0049            48         49
P         49          49          48          47          46          45          44          43          42 name_0049  name_0048  name_0047  name_0046  name_0045  name_0044  name_0043  name_0042  name_0049  name_0050            49         50
P         50          50          49          48          47          46          45          44          43 name_0050  name_0049  name_0048  name_0047  name_0046  name_0045  name_0044  name_0043  name_0050  name_0051            50         51
P         51          51          50          49          48          47          46          45          44 name_0051  name_0050  name_0049  name_0048  name_0047  name_0046  name_0045  name_0044  name_0051  name_0052            51         52
P         52          52          51          50          49          48          47          46          45 name_0052  name_0051  name_0050  name_0049  name_0048  name_0047  name_0046  name_0045  name_0052  name_0053            52         53
P         53          53          52          51          50          49          48          47          46 name_0053  name_0052  name_0051  name_0050  name_0049  name_0048  name_0047  name_0046  name_0053  name_0054            53         54
P         54          54          53          52          51          50          49          48          47 name_0054  name_0053  name_0052  name_0051  name_0050  name_0049  name_0048  name_0047  name_0054  name_0055            54         55
P         55          55          54          53          52          51          50          49          48 name_0055  name_0054  name_0053  name_0052  name_0051  name_0050  name_0049  name_0048  name_0055  name_0056            55         56
P         56          56          55          54          53          52          51          50          49 name_0056  name_0055  name_0054  name_0053  name_0052  name_0051  name_0050  name_0049  name_0056  name_0057            56         57
P         57          57          56          55          54          53          52          51          50 name_0057  name_0056  name_0055  name_0054  name_0053  name_0052  name_0051  name_0050  name_0057  name_0058            57         58
P         58          58          57          56          55          54          53          52          51 name_0058  name_0057  name_0056  name_0055  name_0054  name_0053  name_0052  name_0051  name_0058  name_0059            58         59
P         59          59          58          57          56          55          54          53          52 name_0059  name_0058  name_0057  name_0056  name_0055  name_0054  name_0053  name_0052  name_0059  name_0060            59         60
P         60          60          59          58          57          56          55          54          53 name_0060  name_0059  name_0058  name_0057  name_0056  name_0055  name_0054  name_0053  name_0060  name_0061            60         61
P         61          61          60          59          58          57          56          55          54 name_0061  name_0060  name_0059  name_0058  name_0057  name_0056  name_0055  name_0054  name_0061  name_0062            61         62
P         62          62          61          60          59          58          57          56          55 name_0062  name_0061  name_0060  name_0059  name_0058  name_0057  name_0056  name_0055  name_0062  name_0063            62         63
P         63          63          62          61          60          59          58          57          56 name_0063  name_0062  name_0061  name_0060  name_0059  name_0058  name_0057  name_0056  name_0063  name_0064            63         64
P         64          64          63          62          61          60          59          58          57 name_0064  name_0063  name_0062  name_0061  name_0060  name_0059  name_0058  name_0057  name_0064  name_0065            64         65
P         65          65          64          63          62          61          60          59          58 name_0065  name_0064  name_0063  name_0062  name_0061  name_0060  name_0059  name_0058  name_0065  name_0066            65         66
P         66          66          65          64          63          62          61          60          59 name_0066  name_0065  name_0064  name_0063  name_0062  name_0061  name_0060  name_0059  name_0066  name_0067            66         67
P         67          67          66          65          64          63          62          61          60 name_0067  name_0066  name_0065  name_0064  name_0063  name_0062  name_0061  name_0060  name_0067  name_0068            67         68
P         68          68          67          66          65          64          63          62          61 name_0068  name_0067  name_0066  name_0065  name_0064  name_0063  name_0062  name_0061  name_0068  name_0069            68         69
P         69          69          68          67          66          65          64          63          62 name_0069  name_0068  name_0067  name_0066  name_0065  name_0064  name_0063  name_0062  name_0069  name_0070            69         70
P         70          70          69          68          67          66          65          64          63 name_0070  name_0069  name_0068  name_0067  name_0066  name_0065  name_0064  name_0063  name_0070  name_0071            70         71
P         71          71          70          69          68          67          66          65          64 name_0071  name_0070  name_0069  name_0068  name_0067  name_0066  name_0065  name_0064  name_0071  name_0072            71         72
P         72          72          71          70          69          68          67          66          65 name_0072  name_0071  name_0070  name_0069  name_0068  name_0067  name_0066  name_0065  name_0072  name_0073            72         73
P         73          73          72          71          70          69          68          67          66 name_0073  name_0072  name_0071  name_0070  name_0069  name_0068  name_0067  name_0066  name_0073  name_0074            73         74
P         74          74          73          72          71          70          69          68          67 name_0074  name_0073  name_0072  name_0071  name_0070  name_0069  name_0068  name_0067  name_0074  name_0075            74         75
P         75          75          74          73          72          71          70          69          68 name_0075  name_0074  name_0073  name_0072  name_0071  name_0070  name_0069  name_0068  name_0075  name_0076            75         76
P         76          76          75          74          73          72          71          70          69 name_0076  name_0075  name_0074  name_0073  name_0072  name_0071  name_0070  name_0069  name_0076  name_0077            76         77
P         77          77          76          75          74          73          72          71          70 name_0077  name_0076  name_0075  name_0074  name_0073  name_0072  name_0071  name_0070  name_0077  name_0078            77         78
P         78          78          77          76          75          74          73          72          71 name_0078  name_0077  name_0076  name_0075  name_0074  name_0073  name_0072  name_0071  name_0078  name_0079            78         79
P         79          79          78          77          76          75          74          73          72 name_0079  name_0078  name_0077  name_0076  name_0075  name_0074  name_0073  name_0072  name_0079  name_0080            79         80
P         80          80          79          78          77          76          75          74          73 name_0080  name_0079  name_0078  name_0077  name_0076  name_0075  name_0074  name_0073  name_0080  name_0081            80         81
P         81          81          80          79          78          77          76          75          74 name_0081  name_0080  name_0079  name_0078  name_0077  name_0076  name_0075  name_0074  name_0081  name_0082            81         82
P         82          82          81          80          79          78          77          76          75 name_0082  name_0081  name_0080  name_0079  name_0078  name_0077  name_0076  name_0075  name_0082  name_0083            82         83
P         83          83          82          81          80          79          78          77          76 name_0083  name_0082  name_0081  name_0080  name_0079  name_0078  name_0077  name_0076  name_0083  name_0084            83         84
P         84          84          83          82          81          80          79          78          77 name_0084  name_0083  name_0082  name_0081  name_0080  name_0079  name_0078  name_0077  name_0084  name_0085            84         85
P         85          85          84          83          82          81          80          79          78 name_0085  name_0084  name_0083  name_0082  name_0081  name_0080  name_0079  name_0078  name_0085  name_0086            85         86
P         86          86          85          84          83          82          81          80          79 name_0086  name_0085  name_0084  name_0083  name_0082  name_0081  name_0080  name_0079  name_0086  name_0087            86         87
P         87          87          86          85          84          83          82          81          80 name_0087  name_0086  name_0085  name_0084  name_0083  name_0082  name_0081  name_0080  name_0087  name_0088            87         88
P         88          88          87          86          85          84          83          82          81 name_0088  name_0087  name_0086  name_0085  name_0084  name_0083  name_0082  name_0081  name_0088  name_0089            88         89
P         89          89          88          87          86          85          84          83          82 name_0089  name_0088  name_0087  name_0086  name_0085  name_0084  name_0083  name_0082  name_0089  name_0090            89         90
P         90          90          89          88          87          86          85          84          83 name_0090  name_0089  name_0088  name_0087  name_0086  name_0085  name_0084  name_0083  name_0090  name_0091            90         91
P         91          91          90          89          88          87          86          85          84 name_0091  name_0090  name_0089  name_0088  name_0087  name_0086  name_0085  name_0084  name_0091  name_0092            91         92
P         92          92          91          90          89          88          87          86          85 name_0092  name_0091  name_0090  name_0089  name_0088  name_0087  name_0086  name_0085  name_0092  name_0093            92         93
P         93          93          92          91          90          89          88          87          86 name_0093  name_0092  name_0091  name_0090  name_0089  name_0088  name_0087  name_0086  name_0093  name_0094            93         94
P         94          94          93          92          91          90          89          88          87 name_0094  name_0093  name_0092  name_0091  name_0090  name_0089  name_0088  name_0087  name_0094  name_0095            94         95
P         95          95          94          93          92          91          90          89          88 name_0095  name_0094  name_0093  name_0092  name_0091  name_0090  name_0089  name_0088  name_0095  name_0096            95         96
P         96          96          95          94          93          92          91          90          89 name_0096  name_0095  name_0094  name_0093  name_0092  name_0091  name_0090  name_0089  name_0096  name_0097            96         97
P         97          97          96          95          94          93          92          91          90 name_0097  name_0096  name_0095  name_0094  name_0093  name_0092  name_0091  name_0090  name_0097  name_0098            97         98
P         98          98          97          96          95          94          93          92          91 name_0098  name_0097  name_0096  name_0095  name_0094  name_0093  name_0092  name_0091  name_0098  name_0099            98         99
P         99          99          98          97          96          95          94          93          92 name_0099  name_0098  name_0097  name_0096  name_0095  name_0094  name_0093  name_0092  name_0099  name_0100            99        100
```

So you can take this example and modify it for your needs: add required number of previous data(9-20), change column names, remove unneeded columns.